Show an Enter button on iOS keyboard on numeric input
I have an input for a zipcode:
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" onKeyPress=...>

It's all good on Android but on iOS it does not provide an "Enter" or "Go" button on the keyboard (see screenshot).
How can I make iOS show a button to "Enter"?

Thanks
